# Library for creating animated png

Tags: c#, png, apng

I am looking for an [APNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) encoder in native c#, that does not rely on c/c++ libraries. So far I have only found a few readers and I'd like to avoid writing that library myself if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately not. I ended up writing it myself.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36179/APNG-Viewer) is an APNG viewer/parser article with source code on CodeProject. It might give you what you need.

On Github, there is [this](https://github.com/xupefei/APNG.NET) APNG parser.

Otherwise, if you give up on finding a native C# library, [here](http://code.google.com/p/sharpapng/) is a complete C/C++ toolkit including a C# wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I've coded a C# PNG coder ([PngCs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pngcs/)) and lately I've evaluating adding APNG support to it, but, after reading the spec, I doubt I will try it - I really don't like the APNG approach. But the source code is available, it could be a starting point for writing your own APNG coder.